# Find a substring and print it until specific character

Tags: python

I have a similar sting to this:

`"Name: Carl, Age: 21, Location: US,"`

I would like to use python to find a specific substring and print its value. Like finding the word `"Age"` and then printing that until the comma.

The result should be `"Age: 21"`. Is this possible? I've been searching around for a while now but I can't find anything.

Comment: Look at regular expressions. For example `re.search(r'Age: (\d+)', your_string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions would be the solution. If you don't want to use those. splitting the string and checking would be possible too.

```
text = "Name: Carl, Age: 21, Location: US,"
for items in text.split(','):
    if "Age" in items:
        print(items)
```

Gives you:

```
Age: 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Andrej Kesely said, a library called regualr expressions will help you out:

```
import re                                       # import regualr expressions

s = 'Name: Carl, Age: 21, Location: US,'
result = re.search('Age: (.*), Location:', s)   # gets all strings between "Age: " 
                                                # and ", Location:"
print("Age: " + result.group(1))                # print the first accordance
```

Output:

```
Age: 21
```